# SQL select where associated columns set equals query set

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have **table1** associated to **table2** with ONE-TO-MANY relationship where **table2** has columns **"name"** and **"table1_id"** foreign key refers to **id** of **table1**. So I want to know is it possible to select record from **table1** where its **names** list is the same as list I need to check in query. Basically a have to compare two String sets and where they equals return the record. Preferable using "JOIN".

Comment: Please add the sample data and the expected output.

Comment: This piece needs re-worded  "where its names list is the same as list I need to check in query". Did not understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, 'match!'
from table1 t1
inner join (select t2.table1_id as table1_id
                  ,array_agg(t2.name) as names          
            from table2 t2
            group by t2.table1_id
           ) as t2
  on t2.table1_id = t1.id
 and t2.names     = string_to_array(t1.names, ', '/*<--put the delimiter you use in your string here, include spaces if needed*/)
```

Comment: There could be different names ordering inside query

Comment: is the ordering of names in table1 random?

Comment: no, there's random ordering from incoming query names